# How do you find the area of a regular pentagon with side length 1

Tags: geometry

I need to find the area of a regular pentagon with side length 1 exactly.

I would like to do this using the areas of the golden triangles and golden gnomons please.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: This pentagon can be partitioned into $5$ isosceles triangles with base $1$ and vertical angle $72^{\circ}$

Comment: Thanks. I'd rather avoid using trig identities if possible to make this as pure as possible...?

Comment: @Guest i doubt that is possible. Unless someone here is euclid.

Comment: Ok- well I'd stil like an answer in terms of $\phi$ though?

Comment: @Guest You mean$\phi = \frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}$? Interesting.

Comment: @Guest It is surely possible. You can find the values of the trig functions of 72 degrees through geometry easily. Thus you wouldnt have to apply trig anywhere directly.

Comment: @Sawarnik it is a fine line between "purity" and "inefficiency". It would very short calculating the ratios for 72 through either trig, or complex numbers. Geometry is massively inefficient here.

Comment: @Sabyasachi Well, its not that tough. Just a few constructions and you are done. But I agree, calculating it other ways is better. But the OP asked that is a geometry answer possible of which I gave the  answer.

Comment: @Sawarnik fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can divide the pentagon into two golden gnomon and a golden triangle. By using Pythagorean theorem and the fact that the ratio of the sides to the base of a golden triangle is $\phi$ it is pretty easy to find the area of the golden triangle, $A_{gold}=\frac{1}{2}(1)(\sqrt{\phi^2-\frac{1}{4}})$. The trick from here was to redefine the base of the golden triangle to be one of the isosceles sides so that we can use the same base to define the area of the golden triangle and golden gnomon, and we know this length to be $\phi$ since the base of the golden triangle is 1. Since the area is still the same, we have $\frac{1}{2}(\phi)(h)=A_{gold}=\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{\phi^2-\frac{1}{4}})$ where the $h$ is the height of the golden triangle with the isosceles side as the base. Now looking at the golden gnomon, the height defined perpendicular to the side of the golden triangle divides the golden gnomon into two triangles, one of which is similar by AAA to the triangle formed in the golden triangle by the new defined height. So the ratio of the height from the golden triangle to the height of the golden gnomon is $\phi$. And we get $A_{Pent}= \frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{\phi^2-\frac{1}{4}})+2(\frac{1}{2}(\phi)(\frac{\sqrt{\phi^2-\frac{1}{4}}}{\phi^2}))=\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{\phi^2-\frac{1}{4}})+\frac{\sqrt{\phi^2-\frac{1}{4}}}{\phi}$